# How to get the id of the last element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the list of products ,using below code

```
<table id="product">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th style="width:30%;">Item Name</th>
            <th style="width:11%;">Price</th>
            <th style="width:11%;">Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cart_contents">
        <?php $i=1;
            foreach($cart as $line=>$item)
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="align:center;"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  id="price_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>" name="price"></td>
                    <td id="qnty"><input type="text"  id="quantity_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity"></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to edit quantity and price fields of last added product.

```
<table width="297px" style="float:left" class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="click_quantity();"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Qty</a></td>      
        <td onclick="click_price();"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" >Price</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
function click_quantity(){   
    $("#table register").find("td qnty").each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    }) 
}
```

How to get the last quantity field's id, after clicking the `Qty` link?

I have tried some codes, but I am unable to get last element's id.

EX : id names are `quantity_1, quantity_2, quantity_3, quantity_4`.

How to get `quantity_4` (last elment's id)?

Comment: 1) You SHOULD NOT put id in loop, there should only be one param with an id , so change it to class

Comment: 2) if you change qnty to class, your jquery call should be .find("td .qnty")

Comment: Please change `<td onclick="click_quantity();"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Qty</a>` to `<td><a href="#">Qty</a>` and use `$(".CSSTableGenerator")` to find the table you need to add the clicks to. Add e.preventDefault() to the links instead of the horrible void(0)

Comment: After correcting the code as mentioned in above comments.. try this: `$("#table register").find("tr:last .qnty")`.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<table id="product">
<thead>
<tr> 
    <th style="width:30%;">Item Name</th>
    <th style="width:11%;">Price</th>
    <th style="width:11%;">Qty</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="cart_contents">
<?php $i=1;
foreach($cart as $line=>$item)
{
?>
<tr>
    <td style="align:center;"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  id="price_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>" name="price"/>
    </td>
    <td class="qnty">
         <input class="qnty_input" type="text"  id="quantity_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity"/>
    </td>
</tr>
 <?php 
 $i++;
  } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JS Code**

```
  function click_quantity(){
    var id = $("#cart_contents tr:last-child .qnty_input").attr("id");
    // rest of your logic
  }
```

Comment: are u getting any error? kindly make sure jquery is present

Comment: var id = $("#cart_contents tr:last-child .qnty_input").attr("id");
 alert(id);  just put his code,empty alert shows.no jquery error

Comment: need to make sure following things, you have only one cart_contents id on page, inspect page element. and you have put class qnty_input in text box

Answer (score 0):

1) you are using same ID in loop, that is not valid;

2) I think your js is wrong, use : `$("#register").find("#qnty")`, but has to be `find('.qnty')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
var last_id = $( 'table tbody tr td:last-child').attr( 'id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last row(td) in table you can use this,

```
$('table tbody tr td:last-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get last child element you can make use of Try to use last property of jquery

```
$("#cart_contents td:last").find('input[type=text]').attr('id');
```

Comment: but how to get quantity field last id name

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cart_contents td:last")
```

using this you'll find last column in each row so you have to use

```
$("#cart_contents tr:last-child td.qnty")
```

Comment: var id = $("#cart_contents tr:last-child td.qnty").attr("id");alert(id); empty alert shows ,unable to get id name